# Issue with Loading mapquest script dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, leaflet, mapquest

In ASP.NET Core application i have Html template and corresponding Javascript stored in the database as string (in two separate columns).

**Html Template** The `script` and `link` tag are part of the template.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://api.mqcdn.com/sdk/mapquest-js/v1.3.2/mapquest.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://api.mqcdn.com/sdk/mapquest-js/v1.3.2/mapquest.css" />

<div id="mapcontainer" name="mapcontainer"> 
    <div id="map" name="map" style="width: 100%;height: 700px;"/>
</div>
```

**JavaScript Template**

```
$(function(){
        var mapdiv = $("#map")[0]; // get dom element

        var geoJsonData = {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[xxx,xxx],[xxx,xxx],[xxx,xxx],[xxx,xxx],[xxx,xxx]]]]}
        };

        console.log(geoJsonData);

        var boundary;

        L.mapquest.key = 'KEY';

        var myRenderer = L.canvas({ padding: 0.5 });

        var map = L.mapquest.map(mapdiv, {
            center: [35, -84],
            layers: L.mapquest.tileLayer('hybrid'),
            zoom: 4,
            renderer: myRenderer
        });

        if (boundary) {
            map.removeLayer(boundary);
        }

        var myStyle = {
            color: "blue",
            opacity: 1,
            fillColor: "blue",
            fillOpacity: .1
        };

        boundary = L.geoJSON(geoJsonData, { style: myStyle }).addTo(map);
        map.fitBounds(boundary.getBounds());

})
```

**Partial View** that writes html and javascripts. *(Note that javascript template is written after Html)*

```
@model RenderModel

@Html.Raw(Model.Html)

<script type="text/javascript">
    @Html.Raw(Model.Js)
</script>
```

**Action method that returns Partial View**

```
    public IActionResult Render()
    {
        var result = service.GetFromDataBase();
        var renderModel = new RenderModel()
        {
            Html = result.HtmlString;
            Js = model.JsString;
        };

        return PartialView("_RenderedOutput", renderModel);
    }
```

On client side, when user clicks some button i load this partial view using ajax

```
 $("#btn").click(function(){
    $.get("/render",function(data){
       $("#someDiv").html(data);
    })
 })
```

**ISSUE**

when partial view loads i see error in console

```
VM555:16 Uncaught ReferenceError: L is not defined
    at <anonymous>:16:13
    at b (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Ie (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k.fn.init.append (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k.fn.init.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
    at _ (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k.fn.init.html (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.onDone (main.js:66)
    at Object.<anonymous> (wmp.utils.js?v=oqExPOG9vQY_CyC9Di4pALnwKwtHyRC287LMRejP6Hw:167)
    at c (jquery.min.js:2)
```

variable `L` is a part of mapquest javascript so it looks like JavaScript template is getting invoked before mapquest script is loaded. I looked at the mapquest documentation but everywhere they using `window.onload` event which will not work in my case

Answer (score 0):

This won't work. You cannot add scripts to a page via dumping HTML (coming from AJAX or not). For security, the browser will automatically strip any script tags before inserting the HTML into the DOM. If you want to dynamically load scripts, you'll have to do it manually or use a library expressly for the purpose (which basic just does the same thing as the manual approach with more bells and whistles).

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = scriptSrc;
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Where `scriptSrc` would be the URL to the script you want to load. This JS would of course have to be on-page already, or else you're in an infinite recursion where you need something to load this script so you can load the other script etc.

None of this really works all that well with partials. Likely, you're looking for a way to be able to drop a library and all supporting HTML on the page dynamically based on something that's happening client-side. If that's the case, you should remain client-side, and create a component in something like Vue, Angular, React, etc.

Comment: But i see the script tags with `src` rendered in HTML. Browser is not stripping out anything??

Comment: Different browsers may have different displays of what's happening. Regardless of whether they're stripped or simply disabled, the scripts will not be loaded.

Comment: jQuery has `$.getScript` method however Success callback is fired once the script has been loaded but not necessarily executed. And then there is also https://requirejs.org/ which i never used but looks like it also use to load module. Will requireJs work?

Comment: Yes. Anything like that will work. I personally found require.js to be a bit of a pain, but it'll get the job done. There's tons of libraries out there, so it's mostly personal preference. You just need script on page to load the script. You just can't insert HTML with a script tag inside.

Comment: so if i use `getscripts` from jQuery will the variable `L` available in success call back after mapquest script loaded? or does the mapquest script needs to be executed first?